# Multiplication in Salesforce Marketing Cloud SQL

Tags: marketing-cloud

Anybody know why I can use addition `(columnA + columnb) as columnc` in Marketing Cloud SQL, but seemingly not multiplication (as below)? Or am I doing something wrong in this code?:

```
SELECT SubscriberKey,
Product,
Purchases,
Timestamp,
Product_Value,
(Purchases * Product_Value) as Purchases_Value
From Claimed_Purchases_With_Values
```

The resulting query runs, but nothing appears in `Purchases_Value`.

Comment: can you check if the resulting size of the multiplicated value is within the bounds of your attribute size in which you want to store it

Comment: What's the datatype of the column in the target data extension?

Comment: Yeah, it turns out I was trying to multiply a decimal with a number field. I fixed it by changing both to decimal. Have posted it as an answer in case anyone else comes across this.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the comments, which I think were heading for the solution I eventually found.

The data types need to be the same - you can't multiply a number by a decimal or vice versa. Once I changed both to decimal, it worked.